# How to prevent MacOS Mail autocomplete from inserting new line when accepting its suggestion?

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave

When I compose an email in the stock Mail app, it shows potential words via autocomplete.

e.g. typing  *larg* results in '*large*' popping up as a suggestion.

However, when I hit ENTER to select the word, it adds a carriage return/new line.

How can I turn this 'additional newline' behaviour off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SPACE to accept autocorrect suggestion.

If you like to use enter, then you can open dropdown list of suggested words with ⌥ + ESC, navigate to needed word using arrow keys and press Enter (will take cursor at the end of word).

Word you are looking for may or may not be first in list and automatically selected. If this happens to be true then of course no navigation with arrow keys is needed and enter can be pressed right away (⌥+ESC and Enter).

If you use SPACE instead of Enter then space is added between cursor and end of entered word so you can continue writing right away.

Comment: better, but then that also adds a tab, so I still need to hit 'delete' anyway

Comment: My mistake. This feature you are describing is not autocomplete, it is autocorrect. So instead of TAB you should just press SPACE. If you are using ⌥+ESC to bring up list of suggestions, if you press enter on selected word then word is entered and cursor is at the end of the word. If you press SPACE instead of enter then word is entered with space at the end. I clarify my answer.

Comment: how can it be autocorrect if I can see a whole word suggested for my partially typed word? :D

Comment: Try to turn off "Correct spelling automatically" globally and/or in specific app and you will see that there are no suggestions anymore (⌥ + ESC will still work). So I would call it autocorrect rather than autocomplete (which happens to be the name of terminal/shell feature and which works with TAB)

Comment: actually it seems like pressing 'space' works (accepts the suggestion and does not add a new line), what's odd is I would've tried this previously as I know different apps and OSs use different methods e.g.ctrl+space